# VLookup formula not working per the documentation

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Before y'all tell me to search please look at the formulas. I have searched and tried all variations mentioned in the docs. The spreadsheet is dead simple. I am trying to populate the driver name cell based on previously recorded license plates. Why is this not working as the docs show? The result with in B11 should be 'Billy Goats'.

[Formula with no final value specified (should default to TRUE).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUpBG.jpg)

[Formula final value sorted set to TRUE, still not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdHuR.jpg)

[Formula final value sorted set to FALSE, still not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pupwl.jpg)

I am not looking for someone to fix my problem. I just want to know why this is not functioning according to the docs. I am trying to learn, not get free scripting services.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as formulae, error messages and sheet content. In this case, you could post the sheet data as a table (with column & row labels). The formula could be posted in the question body, marked as code. Alternatively, you could include the formula in the cells and within the question body referenced in the usual way (e.g. "B11"). See editing help (look for the "?⃝" when editing) for details on tables and code markup.

Comment: Ignore the images ;) 
In summary, I tried all 3 formulas mentioned in the documentation and none are working.
```=VLOOKUP(F11,A2:E800,2)```

```=VLOOKUP(F11,A2:E800,2,TRUE)```

```=VLOOKUP(F11,A2:E800,2,FALSE)```

Comment: With or without images, a question such as this needs a [mcve]; in this case, what I described earlier counts as such. Please [edit] clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the documentation for [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en), both the description of the formula inputs and the technical details; it explains why the attempt is incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(F11, {E1:E10, B1:B10}, 2, 0)
```

Comment: That formula worked perfectly. I just don't understand why 2 ranges were not suggested in the docs. Thank you both for the help and feedback.

Comment: @JaeNulton the 1st column of a range you use in 2 parameter needs to be the column where 1 parameter of vlookup is got to be found

Comment: The question explicitly says a solution is not desired but rather an explanation why the formulas aren't returning the expected results (which is why it's curious that OP accepted this answer). @JaeNulton: which do you actually want?